# How to use isotope with different size items

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope, masonry

I have few images, with random size, is it possible to use isotope-masonry in that case? I played with it about 2 hours, but I don't understand the options, for example `columnWidth`, `gutterWidth`.. I changed the values but nothing happens. What's wrong with my code?

```
var $container = $('#collection-list').isotope({

// main isotope options
itemSelector: '.item',
layoutMode: 'masonry',

// options for masonry layout mode
masonry: {
    columnWidth: 50,
    gutterWidth: 10
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9SzVD/2/embedded/result/ here is my demo

Comment: I would like a result like this http://s17.postimg.org/fo1hm13gt/Screen_Shot_2014_04_05_at_22_05_34.png if possible